# ReactJS + Typescript : Avoid duplicate properties in the interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Apologies if this is a noob question but I am just beginning React+TS. I am trying to create a card component with the below structure.

```
   App
   |---Cardlist
        |---Card
             |---Message
```

I have user data in this format.

```
 const userData: Array<IUserData> = [
     {
      name: 'Bob',
       designation: 'Sr. Manager',
       companyName: 'Github',
       message: {
         text: 'Call Home!'
       }
     },
     {
       name: 'Max',
       designation: 'Jr. Manager',
       companyName: 'Not Github',
       message: {
         text: 'Call Office!'
       }
     }   ];
```

To use the data in the component in TS, I had to create the interfaces as below.

```
export interface IUserData { name: string; designation: string; companyName: string; message: IMessage;  }

export interface IMessage { name: string; receivedOn?: Date; text: string;  }
```

Note the duplicate name property on the IMessage interface which would be the same as the name it receives from IUserData. I had to duplicate it because I want to show the name value in the messages component and I am unable to do so without adding the property in the interface.

```
export default class Message extends Component<IMessage> {
  render() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    const messageText = this.props.text;

    return (
      <p>
        Hey {name}, here is your latest message:{' '}
        <text style={{ color: 'red', textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>
          {messageText}
        </text>
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

The cards component is as below -

```
export default class Card extends Component<IUserData> {
  render() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    const designation = this.props.designation;
    const companyName = this.props.companyName;
    const message = this.props.message;

    return (
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: '50px' }}>
        <h1>
          {name} : {designation} : {companyName}
        </h1>
        <Message name={name} {...message} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, adding the value in the interface forces me to duplicate the data in the original data array too. Is this way correct ? Is there any way to make this better, avoiding the data duplication ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest fix is to be explicit about `IUserData` as

```
export interface IUserData { 
  name: string; 
  designation: string; 
  companyName: string; 
  message: {
    receivedOn?: Date;
    text: string;
  } 
};
```

and instead think of `IMessage` as `IMessageProps`.

Comment: In that case, I would be replicating the IMessage interface indirectly at two places...

Comment: True. But it's kinda impossible not to, as we want IMessage to be one thing by definition and another thing as Props to the Message component. Alternatively, we could define `interface IMessageProps extends IMessage {name:string};`, but it's essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could make IUserData extending IMessage:

```
export interface IMessage {
    name: string;
    receivedOn?: Date;
    text: string;
}

export interface IUserData extends IMessage {
    designation: string;
    companyName: string;
}
```